# How to find element in nested template

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Polymer element is defined as follows:

```dart
<polymer-element name="my-element">
    <template>
       <template if="{{show==true}}">
           <div on-click="{{hideMe}}"> click to hide my div </div>
           <div id="mydiv">
               my div content here
           </div>
       </template>
     </template>
 </polymer-element>
```

And Dart code is as follows:

```dart
@CustomTag('my-element')
@observable bool show = true;

 hideMe(){
    Element e = $['mydiv'];
    e.hidden = true;
 }
```

Code does not work as $['mydiv'] returns null. 
How to find an element in nested template in Dart polymer component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to do that? `<template if` removes the nodes from the DOM when `show == false`.
All you have to do is

**In HTML**

```dart
`on-click='{{hide}}'`
```

**In Dart**

```dart
void hide() {
  show = false;
}
```

If you don't want to hide the `<div on-click='...>` move it outside the `<template if=...>`

Hint:
If your `show` field is of type bool you can simplify to

```dart
 <template if="{{show}}">
```

Comment: <template if=...> contains several DIV elements. Each DIV displays its own content. User clicks on div to hide (or show) its content so he does not have to scroll the page.

Comment: I would handle this with a (nested) `<template if=...>` as well. Hold the current state of each node in you model and you can easily make a toggle (show/hide) for each node by just modifying the state.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. It works. I was trying to not write View (html) manipulation code in my controller (dart code) but simply set model variable(show) and let view handle UI related logic.  Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `$['id']` seems to fail with nested templates. But there is also the more verbose way, which works.

```dart
Element e = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#mydiv");
```